# Working with an CSV File with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a situation where I have one csv file with over 100 rows the columns look like the following:

```
 path,owner,group,mode
/prod/home/{{ sid }},root,root,755
/prod/FS/{{ sid }},sapadm,sys,770
/prod/FS/{{ sid }},adm,sys,0770
/prod/FS/{{ sid }},adm,sys,0770
/prod/FS/{{ sid }},sys,sys,0770
/prod/FS/{{ sid },adm,ftp,0770
```

Currently I am trying to iterate / loop over the above CSV file within Ansible, within the File Module: The yaml file has the following:

```
---
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      gather_facts: no
      tasks:
        - read_csv:
            path: test.csv
            key: path
          register: test
        - name: Check File Systems for Any changes
          file:
            path: "{{ item.value.path}}"
            owner: "{{ item.value.owner }}"
            group: "{{ item.value.group }}"
            mode: "{{ item.value.mode }}"
            state: directory 
            recurse: no 
          loop: "{{ test.dict|dict2items }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot parse the csv as a dict with `path` as `key` because `path` is not unique in your csv file. It is not really clear how `{{ sid }}` will be handled in that file. This might cause other problems in your subsequent tasks...

In this case it is much easier to parse it as a list by dropping the `key` option to the module:

```
    - read_csv:
        path: test.csv
      register: test
```

Now you can iterate on the result:

```
    - name: Check File Systems for Any changes
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
        group: "{{ item.group }}"
        mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
        state: directory 
        recurse: no 
      loop: "{{ test.list }}"
```